# Bloc event not receiving data even after emitting data correctly?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, bloc, state-management

I am having issue that my Blocbuilder is not getting updated even after i am emitting the changes.
Like when i am fetch the data from the firebase by using StreamBuilder, the data is being fetched correctly and i am storing it in the visibleItem list. I have added a search functionality in which i using bloc and whenever my onchanged method gets called i update the state of it and emit the updated result list, but the issue is the blocbuilder isn't getting that state. I have seen all this by adding debuggers in the code, the result is getting emitted correctly. Please take a look at the code.

CateGoryScreen in which i have fetched the data and showing the data

```
visibleItems =
                searchState.results.where((item) => item.isVisible).toList();

so in this line i am seeing wether that item isVisble or not which is being updated in the searcBloc class
```

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder(
        stream: categoryBloc.categories,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<List<CategoryModel>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            _searchBloc = SearchBloc(snapshot.data ?? []);
            return _buildScreen();
          } else {
            return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
          }
        });
  }

  Widget _buildScreen() {
    final double appBarHeight =
        MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top + kToolbarHeight;

    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return _showDiscardWidget(context);
      },
      child: MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider<ItemSelectionCubit>(create: (_) => ItemSelectionCubit()),
          BlocProvider<SearchBloc>(create: (_) => _searchBloc),
        ],
        child: BlocBuilder<SearchBloc, SearchState>(
          builder: (context, searchState) {
            final bool shouldDisplayBackgorund =
                _searchController.text.isEmpty &&
                    MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom == 0;

            visibleItems =
                searchState.results.where((item) => item.isVisible).toList();
            return BlocBuilder<ItemSelectionCubit, ItemSelectionState>(
              builder: (context, itemSelectionState) {
                return Scaffold(
                  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                  body: SafeArea(
                    top: false,
                    child: CustomScrollView(
                      controller: _scrollController,
                      slivers: [
                        CustomSliverAppBar(
                          maxExtent: shouldDisplayBackgorund
                              ? appBarBackgroundHeight
                              : appBarHeight,
                          minExtent: appBarHeight,
                          appBar: _popupAppbar(
                              appBarHeight, itemSelectionState, context),
                          background: shouldDisplayBackgorund
                              ? _backgroundAppbar(itemSelectionState, context)
                              : null,
                        ),
                        SliverList(
                          delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(
                            [
                              visibleItems.isNotEmpty
                                  ? CategoryItemWidget(itemSelectionState,
                                      visibleItems, searchState.query)
                                  : NoResultFoundWidget(
                                      resultQuery: searchState.query ?? ""),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }  


Widget _popupAppbar(double appBarHeight,
      ItemSelectionState itemSelectionState, BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: appBarHeight,
      width: double.infinity,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(color: Colors.white, boxShadow: [
        BoxShadow(color: Colors.black26, offset: Offset(1, 0), blurRadius: 5),
      ]),
      child: Align(
        alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
        child: SearchAppBar(
          hint: 'Search Category',
          onChanged: (query) {
            _searchBloc.add(SearchQueryChanged(query: query));
          },
          onPressedPrefix: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop();
          },
          onPressedSuffix: () {
            BlocProvider.of<ItemSelectionCubit>(context).toggleView();
          },
          searchController: _searchController,
          onPressedSuffixInSearchBar: () {
            _searchController.clear();
            _searchBloc.add(SearchCleared());
          },
          suffixIconPath: itemSelectionState.isGrid
              ? AppAssetsPath.gridIcon
              : AppAssetsPath.listIcon,
          isExpanding: visibleItems.isEmpty,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
onChanged: (query) {
            _searchBloc.add(SearchQueryChanged(query: query));
          },
so in this i am changing my searchquery here
```

searcBloc class in which my all logic for search is

```
class SearchBloc extends Bloc<SearchEvent, SearchState> {
  final List<CategoryModel> _items;

  SearchBloc(this._items)
      : super(SearchState(
            query: null,
            results: _items.map((item) => item..isVisible = true).toList())) {
    on<SearchQueryChanged>((event, emit) {
      emit(_mapSearchQueryChangedToState(event.query));
    });
    on<SearchCleared>((event, emit) {
      emit(_mapSearchClearedToState());
    });
  }

  void onSearchQueryChanged(String query) {
    add(SearchQueryChanged(
      query: query,
    ));
  }

  void onSearchCleared() {
    add(SearchCleared());
  }

  SearchState _mapSearchQueryChangedToState(String query) {
    final results = _items.map((item) {
      item.isVisible =
          item.displayName!.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase());
      return item;
    }).toList();
    return SearchState(query: query, results: results);
  }

  SearchState _mapSearchClearedToState() {
    final results = _items.map((item) {
      item.isVisible = true;
      return item;
    }).toList();
    return SearchState(query: null, results: results);
  }
}
```

```
class SearchState {
  final String? query;
  final List<CategoryModel> results;

  SearchState({this.query, required this.results});
}
```

```
abstract class SearchEvent {
  const SearchEvent();
}

class SearchQueryChanged extends SearchEvent {
  final String query;

  const SearchQueryChanged({required this.query});
}

class SearchCleared extends SearchEvent {}
```

and categoryBloc where i am fetching the data is

```
class CategoryBloc {
  final _categoryController = StreamController<List<CategoryModel>>.broadcast();
  Stream<List<CategoryModel>> get categories => _categoryController.stream;

  Future<void> fetchCategories() async {
    try {
      await getData<CategoryModel>(
              path: 'common', builder: (data) => CategoryModel.fromJson(data))
          .then((value) {
        _categoryController.sink.add(value);
      });
    } catch (error) {
      print(error);
      _categoryController.sink.addError(error);
    }
  }


  void dispose() {
    _categoryController.close();
  }
}
```

```
  Future<List<T>> getData<T>(
      {required String path,
      required T Function(Map<String, dynamic>) builder}) async {
    List<T> list = [];
    try {
      final response = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection(path)
          .doc('onboardingCategories')
          .get();

      final data = response.data();
      final List<dynamic> rawData = data!['categories'];
      list = rawData.map((item) => builder(item)).toList();
      return list;
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      if (kDebugMode) {
        print("Failed with error '${e.code}': ${e.message}");
      }
      return list;
    } catch (e) {
      throw Exception(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Before fetching the data i tried using sample data only , like creating the sample class and that time i was able to fetch the data correctly, idk what is happening now i am fetching the data correctly, all the data is getting displayed but when i am using search bar it's not updating. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I have seen blocs not emitting states if they were considered identical to the current state, are you sure you are providing correct way to compare your `CategoryModel`s?

Comment: yes i am fetching the data correctly just the search functionality is not working. 
like i am returning different list so it must not be identical.

Comment: then can you please override the `==` of `SearchState ` class and see if the `BlocBuilder` receives the event?

Comment: i think your search state is where the problem is you can easily add equatable package and extend it in your search state

Comment: more also what is on your stream builder can actually be moved inside your searchbloc

Comment: even after extending with equatable, i havent got any change .
and how can i move stream builder in searchBloc without hampering the functionality